# SQL Server 2008R2 Transactional Replication - Move SubscriberDB - Push Subscription

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, transactional-replication, subscriber

SQL Server 2008R2 Transactional Replication - Move SubscriberDB - Push Subscription

I have a requirement to move a subscriber database to a new server outside of a system outage i.e. I cannot stop new transaction from loading into the publisher database.

So far I have attempted to stop the distribution agent and let all un-replicated commands replicate to the subscriber database at Server1. Then backup and restore the subscriber database to Server2.  I have then created a new subscription from Server2 to the existing publication.

This works but only transactions created from that point forward are replicated to the Server2 subscriber database. I also require all the old transactions built up at the distributor database destined to only go to Server1.

Is there a replication command available to update the destination of existing transactions at the distributer to the new subscriber.subscriber_DB?

There is 1 publication with multiple articles. The publication is currently only subscribed to by one database at Server1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working too hard.  Create a subscription on the new server as though you didn't have an existing subscription at all. There are many ways to do this; pick your favorite. I see in your response to another answer that snapshots are a no-go. I have had a lot of success using the "initialize from backup" option (here, "backup" refers to a backup of the publisher). Once the subscriber is in sync after initialization, you're done. You're now clear to "migrate" to the new server.

Comment: So to clarify I can keep current transactions replicating to subscriber Server1 through Publication1. Back up and restore a recent full backup to subscriber Server2. Then at the publisher create a new subscription but chose "initialize from backup". SQL Server will then sync all new transactions created since the backup over to Server2, whilst still replicating new transactions to server1 until everything is matching in all three locations? Sounds good! I'll see if I can get it to work tomorrow.

Comment: That's the gist of it. Just make sure that the time between your backup and when you add the subscription is within your distribution retention. Also, make sure that "allow initialize from backup" is set on the publication. Other than that, you should be good to go.

Comment: I second this option.  Never used it before so didn't realize it auto syncs since the backup was taken which makes sense.  Probably your best option.

Comment: @Zhenny: a little exposition. All of the options for sync_type in sp_addsubscription amount to "from what LSN do I start delivering xacts?". "automatic" = "use pub's LSN at snapshot creation time", "init from backup" = "use backup's LSN", "repl'n support only" = "use pub's current LSN", "init from LSN" = "...".

Answer (score 0):

Due to the distribution agent being specific to each subscribing server, you can't really have a new subscriber take over where an existing subscriber left off.  The only way this would work is if you backup/restore to Server2, temporarily stopped transactions on the publisher, backup/restore log to Server2, create subscriptions with "replication support only", and then re-enable transactions.

Can you not just add subscriptions to the same publication for the new subscriber and kick off the snapshot agent?  That will independently sync Server2 while Server1 continues to stay in sync.  You should then be able to switch to Server2 seamlessly and remove the subscriptions to Server1.

One note of warning though.  I would check the sync_method in syspublications table (or run sp_helppublications) of your publication database to make sure snapshots won't lock the tables in your publisher (by default with SQL Server 2005+, this shouldn't be an issue).  Otherwise, what I just suggested will cause blocking on the publisher until the snapshot finishes.

Also, this is a good reference to understanding how to do snapshots one at a time if you setup replication through the GUI using default settings.  This will be useful for distributing the snapshots over a larger period of time to reduce publisher server load if you have a lot of data to replicate (gigabytes rather than megabytes).
http://www.replicationanswers.com/TransactionalOptimisation.asp

Comment: many thanks for the feedback.I should have added due to the size of each article we dont use snapshots but rather restore a backup and create a subscription with replication support only as suggested.If we used snapshots I would go with your option two. Your first option is what I am trying to achieve but without stopping transactions at the publisher. You may have answered my question though by pointing out that one dist agent is specific to one subscribing server (makes sense when someone else points it out).I'll mark your question as an answer tomorrow depending on other responses